# Is it true that for all .NET operator overload methods must be public and static?

Tags: operator-overloading, clr, cls-compliant

Quoted from C# From CLR

> The CLR specification mandates that operator overload methods be
>   public and static methods.

I checked ECMA-335, but couldn't find any evidence.

So far I know it is true for C# and F#. Is it true for all CLS-compliant language?

Comment: It is most certainly mentioned in ECMA-335, chapter I.10.3.1 and 3.2: ` They
are represented as static methods on the class`

Comment: @HansPassant Thx, found that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's not *really* required to be public, but making it non-static is problematic at execution time. I experimented by starting with this code:

```
using System;

class Oddity
{
    public static Oddity operator+(Oddity x, Oddity y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding oddities");
        return null;
    }
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new Oddity();
        var y = new Oddity();
        var z = x + y;
    }
}
```

... and then running it through `ildasm`, changing things, then using `ilasm` and running the result.

- Changing the accessibility modifier to `assembly` (equivalent to `internal`): all was fine
- Changing the accessibility modifier to `private`: it assembled (which surprised me) but then failed at execution time:

  > Unhandled Exception: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Test.Main()' to access method 'Oddity.op_Addition(Oddity, Oddity)' failed.
  >    at Test.Main()
- Removing the `static` part: it assembled (again, surprising me) but then failed at execution time:

  > Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Oddity Oddity.op_Addition(Oddity, Oddity)'.
  >    at Test.Main()

I suspect these really *should* be caught at assembly time, but as languages are only *expected* to produce operators which are public and static, the validator is a little lax.